# How to load environment variables from .env file using Vite

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, vite, env-file

I want to load environment variables from the `.env` file using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)

I used the `import.meta.env` object as mentioned in [Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables)

`.env` file:

```
TEST_VAR=123F
```

when trying to access this variable via the `import.meta.env` -> `import.meta.env.TEST_VAR` it returns undefined.

so, how can I access them?

Comment: Only those with VITE_ prefix will be visible inside your JS / Vue code. Check their documentation https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: You need to use VITE_APP_xxxxxx to define the variables in the ENV file.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files), you need to prefix your variables with `VITE_`:

> To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only
> variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code.

If you are trying to access env vars outside your app source code (such as inside `vite.config.js`), then you have to use `loadEnv()`:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default ({ mode }) => {
    // Load app-level env vars to node-level env vars.
    process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())};

    return defineConfig({
      // To access env vars here use process.env.TEST_VAR
    });
}
```

### For SvelteKit

```
// vite.config.js

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default ({ mode }) => {
    // Extends 'process.env.*' with VITE_*-variables from '.env.(mode=production|development)'
    process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())};
    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [sveltekit()]
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'm using Vite with Svelte (not svelteKit) to generate code for browsers and obviously I misinterpreted the Vite documentation, I expected that .env was always included automatically, since it doesn't work and adding loadEnv in the config works i would say that's not the case.

Comment: The linked docs (https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) don't mention using `loadEnv` - they seem to imply that the presence of `.env` in the root will load `VITE_` env vars implicitly. `loadEnv` seems to be required, but I don't see it in the docs O.o. Vite version: 3.1.4

Comment: Good catch. The doc for `loadEnv` (https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-javascript.html#loadenv) permits to see that we can change the prefix: `process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "VUE_")};`

Comment: thank you, I just had to add `VITE_` at the beginning.

Comment: Does anyone know how to access production environment variables from a cloud deployment? I assume I'll need a conditional statement to seek them, but is there a particular reference for them? I.e. in python it's os.environ.

Comment: just remember to restart your server.. was stuck on that.

Answer (score 112):

if you want to access your env variable TEST_VAR you should prefix it with `VITE_`

try something like

```
VITE_TEST_VAR=123f
```

you can access it with

```
import.meta.env.VITE_TEST_VAR
```

Comment: but with import.meta.env I get an error that the meta name is not found

Comment: I do not know why it throws an error, but `// @ts-ignore` on the line above helps 

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript

Comment: In `Node.js` you can access it regularly with `process.env.VITE_TEST_VAR`

Comment: @EliZatlawy no you can't

Comment: Yeah, it was work.

Answer (score 61):

Here are three mistakes/gotchas that tripped me up.

- Ensure the .env files are in the root, not the `src` directory.  The filename `.env` and/or `.env.development` will work when running locally.
- Restart the local web server for the variables to appear: `npm run dev`
- Prefix the variables with `VITE_` (as already mentioned by Mahmoud and Wonkledge)

Comment: Alternatively, setting `envDir` option in `vite.config.ts`: 

```typescript
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  envDir: './src/environments'
})
```

Comment: What tripped me up was not realizing I had created my `.env.development` file in the `src` folder instead of the root dir 

Comment: Note that when the vite docs mention `root`, they mean the project root (i.e. where `index.html` is), and not the top-level project folder. These are not the same if you have [set the `root` option](https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#root). @bishop I presume you have `root: "./src"` set.

Comment: I just wasted two hours because my env file was outside my project folder

Answer (score 20):

Another solution that worked for me is to manually call `dotenv.config()` inside the `vite.config.js`. That will load variables from `.env` (all of them!) into `process.env`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config() // load env vars from .env

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    __VALUE__: `"${process.env.VALUE}"` // wrapping in "" since it's a string
  },
  //....
}
```

where `.env` file could be:

```
VALUE='My env var value'
```

See [the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-uqluaw?file=vite.config.js&terminal=dev).

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html), you can change the prefix by mdoify `envPrefix`.

> Env variables starting with `envPrefix` will be exposed to your client source code via import.meta.env.

So changing it to `TEST_` will also work.

```
export default defineConfig({
...
  envPrefix: 'TEST_',
...
})
```

You can change this option whatever you want **except** for empty string(`''`).

> `envPrefix` should not be set as `''`, which will expose all your env variables and cause unexpected leaking of sensitive information. Vite will throw an error when detecting `''`.

So overriding the dotenv config directly to remove prefix completely could be an inappropriate action as all fields written in env would send directly into the client.

Answer (score 3):

I got `.env` to work using:

```js
const env = await import.meta.env;
export const version = (env.VITE_APP_VERSION);
export const buildDate = (env.VITE_APP_BUILD_TIME);
```

The key thing was `await`.

This will also work in `.env.development` / cmd: `VITE_APP_VERSION=development vite`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that import.meta.env.VITE_API is returning undefined. To troubleshoot, follow these steps:

- Save the .env file at the root of your project.
- Check the variable name in the .env file matches what you're accessing in your code.
- Restart the Vite development server to apply changes from the .env file.
- Ensure the dotenv configuration is correctly set up in your vite.config.js.
- Verify you're using a Vite version that supports import.meta.env.
- Confirm that you're importing and using import.meta.env.VITE_API correctly in your code. If you've followed these steps and still face issues, provide more context or code snippets for further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the issue was that I had created my `.env.local` file in the src folder instead of the root dir, if you change that it will work just fine calling the variable as you are doing it `import.meta.env`

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')

  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    // vite config
    define: {
      ...Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, key) => {
        prev[`process.env.${key}`] = JSON.stringify(env[key])
        return prev
      }, {}),
    },
  }
})
```

You can use this above code and issue will be resolved now you can use `process.env.VARIALBE_NAME` like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by running

```
pnpm add dot-env
pnpm add -S  dotenv-webpack.
```

Lastly I made sure that I added `VITE_` before the name I had for my environment variable, that is from `MAP_API_KEY` to `VITE_MAP_API_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy to use environment variable if you used vite for generating react boiler plate code.

All you have to do is prefix all of your environment variables with `VITE_`.
example: Suppose you have env variable called `MY_API = xyz`
then change it to: `VITE_MY_API = xyz`

then simply use `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_API`.

```
const App = () => {
   return <div>{import.meta.env.VITE_MY_API}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, so here are a few suggestions to address it when using .env with Vite:

1. First, try directly pasting the source of the key. If it works, it's likely an issue with your .env configurations.
2. Place the .env files in the root directory, not the src directory. Regardless of whether you choose .env or .env.development as the filename, it should work when running locally.
3. After modifying the .env files, be sure to restart the local web server (npm run dev) to ensure that the updated variables take effect.
4. To ensure proper recognition, remember to prefix the variables with VITE_. This step is crucial for their correct functionality.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this, you may need to import the dotenv library for it to work:

```
 npm install dotenv --save
```

This solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score -5):

```js
To load environment variables from.env file using Vite, you need to follow these steps:

  Install the dotenv library with npm:
  npm install dotenv
Create a.env file in the root directory of your project and add your environment variables to it.
For example: #contents of .env
VITE_API_KEY = my - secret - api - key
Prefix your environment variables with VITE_ to make them accessible to your Vite - processed code.For example:
  VITE_API_KEY = my - secret - api - key
Import the environment variables in your code using the
import.meta.env object.For example:
  // import the environment variable
  const apiKey =
    import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;

// use the environment variable
console.log(apiKey); // prints my-secret-api-key
Restart the server after making changes to the.env file.
For more information, you can refer to the official documentation: https: //vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you notice that the formatting in your question is completely broken? Please fix it