# How to I access my .env variables from a vitest test?

Tags: dotenv, vitest

I am trying to migrate my tests from jest to vitest. I have a test suite that uses the dotenv package to pull in my .env variables.

I have this in my test suite

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
        vi.clearAllMocks();
        cleanUpMetadata();
        dotenv.config();
        controller = new UserController(container.get<UserServiceLocator>(Symbol.for("UserServiceLocator")),
            container.get<EmailServiceLocator>(Symbol.for("EmailServiceLocator")));
    });
```

and this is the code in the test that has the undefined variable

```js
let requestObj = httpMocks.createRequest({
            cookies: {
                token: jwt.sign({ username: "testusername" }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY!)
            }
        });
```

Is there something special to vitest that i have to do in order to get my .env variables to be accessible?

Answer (score 21):

You can include the dotenv package(if thats what you are using) into the vitest.config.ts file, it will look something like this below:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  root: '.',
  esbuild: {
    tsconfigRaw: '{}',
  },
  test: {
    clearMocks: true,
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'] //this line,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '~', replacement: resolve(__dirname, 'src') }],
  },
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2023

Comment: this works, this should be the accepted answer in 2024

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but my workaround to this was parsing my .env file inside vitest.config:

```js
import { config } from "dotenv";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    passWithNoTests: true,
    globals: true,
    coverage: {
      provider: "v8",
      exclude: ["**/tests/**"],
    },
    env: {
      ...config({ path: "./env/.testing.env" }).parsed,
    },
  },
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
});
```

This allows me to have multiple config files using `mergeConfig` from Vitest in case of multiple testing environments.

If I'm not wrong you can also do this by setting up `setup` and `teardown` functions as a global setup files.

```js
export async function setup() {
  // LOAD .ENV HERE
  app.listen(env.PORT, () => {
    console.log("Started testing server...");
  });
}

export async function teardown() {
  await app.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import.meta.env.%VARIABLE_NAME%
```

Got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711231

Answer (score 0):

In `Node.js` Assuming you want to access your env variable `VAR` you should prefix it with `VITE_` like:

```
VITE_VAR=123
```

then you can access it regularly with `process.env.VITE_VAR`

Answer (score 0):

`vitest` will automatically load your `.env` file(s) from the project *root* directory, which probably isn't the same directory as your *test* files. Your file structure might look something like this:

```
 project
   .env
   package.json
   vite.config.json
   src/
     myCode.js
   test/
     myCode.test.js
```

In node, you access a variable using `import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VARIABLE_NAME`. In HTML, use the [special syntax](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#html-env-replacement) `%VITE_MY_VARIABLE_NAME%`.

If you're still getting undefined variables, add the [`VITE_`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) prefix to your variable name, which tells `vite` the value is safe to expose.

Comment: doesn't work......

Answer (score 0):

I use the vitest `loadEnv` function in `vitest.config.ts` and that works:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import { loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        environment: 'jsdom',
        env: loadEnv('', process.cwd(), ''),
    },
})
```