# Using Vite, import.meta becomes import_meta and breaks env variables

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I just upgraded a project from Vue CLI to Vite.

One of the packages I use, which I published (open source, separate from this project) was relying on a `VUE_APP_` variable. Per the VITE docs, these should be redefined with a `VITE_` prefix and imported like `import.meta.env.VITE_MANTLE_URL`

Except... as soon as I fire up the dev server, it errors out on that import - a good ol' `Cannot read properties of undefined`. Looking at the devtools, the JS looks like this:

```
var import_meta = {};
var Connection = import_axios.default.create({
  baseURL: import_meta.env.VITE_MANTLE_URL || "/"
});
```

I don't even know where to start with this one. Why is Vite doing this? Is it even a Vite issue? How do I make it not do this? I'm not sure what code to even include here, but will provide what I can if you know what to share.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load environment variables from .env file using Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709987/how-to-load-environment-variables-from-env-file-using-vite).

Answer (score 0):

Ends up that the version of Vite I was using had this issue (2.x, though this appears to be a problem at least through mid-Vite-3.X)

Updated to the latest Vite version and the issue is resolved.